# Image in Lightbox hangs outside of container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I build a responsive lightbox with flexbox-styling and the image in this lightbox doesnt fit in the container. (Its working fine if there is enough vertical space).

Here is a image to visualize the problem:
[image]

Thats the HTML code:

```
<div id="dialog-container">
  <div id="dialog">
    <div id="dialog-content">
      <div class="image-wrapper">
        <img src="https://spotwild.org/css/images/dist/header/header-07-1600.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="thumbs">
        Here are the thumbs
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#dialog-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#dialog {
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 80%;
  background: white;
  padding: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

#dialog-content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.image-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
}

img {
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.thumbs {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

And here is the corresponding jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ppkzt7m6/1/

Does somebody has a solution and an explanation why this happens?

Comment: It looks from your screen shot you are using Lightbox Version 1. If so, I would highly recommend using [Lightbox Version 2](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)

Comment: No, I don't use any library at all

Comment: Lightbox does what you're trying to build, there's little point reinventing the wheel....

Answer (score 1):

The important part is to define the `height` on all the parent containers for the `<img>` element to make the percentage heights to work properly.

And use `object-fit: cover;` on the `<img>` element. Note, the current IE11 and Edge don't support it, works fine on all other modern browsers though, see the [support tables](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit).

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uu88Lbp1/)**

You can also do it without flexbox, the key is to set the image caption to absolute position

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kj9t290d/)**

I suggest to use background image if you do need to support IE, example:

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bawnajw9/)**

```
<div class="image-wrapper" style="background: url('https://spotwild.org/css/images/dist/header/header-07-1600.jpg') center / cover;">
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer! It's not exactly what I want. Is there really no solution to make this work with flexbox and a variable container size?

Answer (score 0):

add height in #dialog

```
#dialog {
    background: white none repeat scroll 0 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 80%;
    max-width: 80%;
    padding: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I've added the height, but now i've got the issue, that the image wont resize anymore: https://jsfiddle.net/ppkzt7m6/3/

Answer (score 0):

**USE THIS.**

```
img {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 0;
    min-width: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#dialog {
    background: #ffffff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 80%;
    max-width: 80%;
    padding: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: But it is working fine for me.may i know exact problem?

Comment: As you can see in the jsfiddle, the height of the image doesn't change anymore.